# Derivation of the Backpropagation Algorithm

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, neural-networks

I'm studying the Backpropagation algorithm and I want to derive it by myself.
Therefore, I've constructed a very simple network with one input layer, one hidden layer and one output layer. You can find the details in the graphic.

The network can be found here:

[image]

$t$ is the true output,  $i$ is the input, $z_{hi}$ and $w_{ij}$ are the weights. Moreover I have the activation function $\phi(x)$.

I think that I have understood the algorithm more or less, so I've started with the following error function:

$$
E = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^2{(t_j-o_j)^2} 
$$

That function should be correct, isn't it?
The next step is to calculate the partial derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial E }{\partial w_{ik}} = \frac{\partial E }{\partial o_k}\cdot  \frac{\partial o_k }{\partial w_{ik}} = -(t_k-o_k) \cdot  \frac{\partial o_k }{\partial w_{ik}} =-(t_k-o_k) \cdot  \phi'(\sum_{i=1}^2 w_{i,k}\cdot a_k ) \cdot a_k
$$

For me that seems to be correct, but is that right up to here (Especially the formal math aspects)? I'm asking, because i have so problems with the next steps (derivating to the z's...

Thanks for helping!